# Not able to resolve Datatable SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am not be able to resolve following Datatables error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined or
>   null reference

I  tried to look all over the internet and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904708/) to be the best solution. But I am still not able to resolve this issue. Am I missing something here? I am a newbie in JavaScript.

Comment: Here is the [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/245223) that solved that for me

Answer (score 36):

Basically this issue came out because of miss matching count of th to td. be sure for number of th matches to td. hope this will help you.

Comment: This is basically it for me. The number of columns added should be the same as number initialized.

Comment: saved my moment

Comment: For me, I was loading the data on table using ajax, but calling the function `$('#TableID').DataTable()` before any data was loaded in the table, thus having this issue. So, I needed to call this function in `success: function()` of ajax call after loading the table data.

Answer (score 13):

We had the same error! What fixed it for us was changing the `target` in the `dataTable` initialization based on the number of columns starting from 0.

In our table we had 4 columns so `targets: [3]`

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults,{
  columnDefs: [{ 
    targets: [3]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case, using colspan in a row, the number of cells didn't match the table headers so this error shows. you can add these hidden cells to get rid of that error.

try this

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">details</td>
    <td style="display: none"></td>
    <td style="display: none"></td>
    <td style="display: none"></td>
</tr>
```

add the required cells but hide them

Comment: Hello, an answer without details  is not really helpfull. Can you please add more details? why this will fix the issue?

Comment: In my case, using colspan in a row, the number of cells didn't match the table headers so this error shows. you can add these hidden cells to get rid of that error.

Comment: Edit your answer :)

Comment: This is clever answer that is worked after applying many stackoverflow answer solutions  +1

Answer (score 3):

found this answer here: [datatable forums](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32575/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-dt-cellindex-of-undefined)

> A simple mistake, the table header had a column " with no
>   title, but the column did not exist in the table itself. I could not
>   see it missing (because o no title and no borders).

did it work?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work out.....Do you know how can i check if my table thead  tag td is matching  with  my table  tbody td?

Comment: Hi @a7madgamal let me upload code on jsbin but .. below is the code where IE 11  gets stuck:-for ( i=0, iLen=oSettings.aoColumns.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
   {
    oCol = oSettings.aoColumns[i];
 
    nTd = nTrIn ? anTds[i] : document.createElement( oCol.sCellType );
    nTd._DT_CellIndex = {
     row: iRow,
     column: i
    };

Answer (score 1):

I had the error, when there was no data in the data table. The table is empty. After adding one record, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Check the count of your table column and `dtColumnDefs`.

If you have 6 columns then below will be your configuration for `dtColumnDefs`.

```
self.dtColumnDefs = [
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(3),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(4),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(5)
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It was **js** part vs **html**.

Problem happened when I deleted html column and forgot to delete a js column that looked like this.

```
        {"name": "Product", "orderable": true,  "searchable": true},
```

Once I deleted the extra column in js everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error:

> Unable to set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

First I tell you that `$("id_tu_tabla").Datatable()` have a minimum number of columns, it is 6. But if you have less than that, you have specify it, like with this code:

```
$('#table').DataTable({ columnDefs: [ { goals: [4]  }]  });  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like many people got the error because of th and td mismatch. For me I got the error with what seemed to be a logical error. Look the code below.

**Note:** This was me experimenting with datatables in Angular 7, enhance things like *ngFor, ng-container, *ngIf, but never mind these, just look at the code structural difference (swapped `tr` with `ng-container`).

Table head:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Organisation</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

This produce the error:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users; let index = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="showInactiveUsers">
    <td>{{user?.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{user?.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{user?.email}}</td>
    <td>{{user?.attributes?.organisation}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!showInactiveUsers && user?.enabled">
    <td>{{user?.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{user?.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{user?.email}}</td>
    <td>{{user?.attributes?.organisation}}</td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Rearranging the code like below solves the error:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users; let index = index">
  <tr *ngIf="showInactiveUsers">
    <td>{{user?.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{user?.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{user?.email}}</td>
    <td>{{user?.attributes?.organisation}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="!showInactiveUsers && user?.enabled">
    <td>{{user?.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{user?.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{user?.email}}</td>
    <td>{{user?.attributes?.organisation}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="user?.enabled">
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you requirement is to show the row with "No record found" message like below code

```
@if(Model.Count==0)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                No record found.
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

then just simple remove this condition because datatable itself append "No data available in table" message, in my case it's resolve the my error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was fixed by removing the '$' sign which was among the column name. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. In my case, I was having 5 columns but in orderable targets, I was setting up to 7 columns. so make sure you do not have extra columns mentioned in the orderable targets too.

```
{ "orderable": false, "targets": [1,2,3,4] }
```