# Angular nested Data Tables with dynamic headers issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using [Angular DataTables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables) in my application and trying to create `nested datatables` with `dynamic headers`.

Here is my Html code.

```
<table datatable="ng" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" dt-instance="dtInstance2" id="dtInvoicingData2"  dt-options="dtOptions2" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="col in dtColumnDefs2">{{col.aTargets[0].sTitle | translate}} </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(index,client) in lstInvoiceDetail" class="clickableRow" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Click to toggle collapse/expand day summaries for this store.">
            <td ng-repeat="col in headerList2" ng-switch="col">
                <span ng-switch-when="lstDetail"> <button type="button" ng-click="btnViewDetails_Click(index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">+</button></span>
                <span ng-switch-default>{{ client[col] }}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="showViewDetail">
           <div class="span12 pull-right" ng-show="showViewDetail">
               <table datatable="ng"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" dt-instance="dtInstance3" id="dtInvoicingData3"  dt-options="dtOptions3" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs3">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th ng-repeat="col3 in dtColumnDefs3">{{col3.aTargets[0].sTitle | translate}} </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="(index,client) in lstInvoiceDetail" class="clickableRow" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Click to toggle collapse/expand day summaries for this store.">
                        <td ng-repeat="col3 in headerList3" ng-switch="col">
                            <span ng-switch-when="lstDetail"> <button type="button" ng-click="btnViewDetails_Click(index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">+</button></span>
                            <span ng-switch-default>{{ client[col3] }}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>                            
        </tr>               
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is javascript Code

```
  function makeDetailTable(data) {          
        var header = data[0],
        dtColumns = [];
        $scope.headerList2 = [];
        var i = 0;
        var key = "";
        //create columns based on first row in Parent Datatable
        for (var key in header) {

             dtColumns.push(DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(i).withTitle(key));
             $scope.headerList2.push(key);
            i = i + 1;


        }

        $scope.dtColumnDefs2 = dtColumns;           

        $scope.dtOptions2 = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()            
                            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')           
                            .withButtons([
                                'excel',
                                    {
                                        text: 'Reset',
                                        action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                                            $("#dtInvoicingData2").DataTable().search("").draw();
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]);
    }

    $scope.btnViewDetails_Click = function (rowIndex) { 
        var detailList = $scope.lstInvoiceDetail[rowIndex]['lstDetail'];            
        var header3 = detailList[0],
        dtColumns3 = [];
        $scope.headerList3 = [];
        var i = 0;
        var key = "";
        //create columns based on first row in child datatable
        for (var key in header3) {

             dtColumns3.push(DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(i).withTitle(key));
             $scope.headerList3.push(key);
            i = i + 1;


        }

        $scope.dtColumnDefs3 = dtColumns3;
        $scope.dtInstance2 = null;
        $scope.dtOptions3 = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()   
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withButtons([
                'excel',
                    {
                        text: 'Reset',
                        action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                            $("#dtInvoicingData3").DataTable().search("").draw();
                        }
                    }
                ]);

        $scope.showViewDetail = true;
```

when I try to add child datatable it doesn't work and show console error

> TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

I did search on this error but i have not find proper solution

[Here is a little info related to this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706384/not-able-to-resolve-datatable-script5007-unable-to-set-property-dt-cellindex)

it says the problem is

`Basically this issue came out because of miss matching count of th to td. be sure for number of th matches to td. hope this will help you.`

**Update:**

Now i have trying this.

```
 <table datatable="ng" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" dt-instance="dtInstance2" id="dtInvoicingData2"  dt-options="dtOptions2" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs2">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th ng-repeat="col in dtColumnDefs2">{{col.aTargets[0].sTitle | translate}} </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                         <tr ng-repeat="(index,client) in lstInvoiceDetail" class="clickableRow" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Click to toggle collapse/expand day summaries for this store.">
                             <td ng-repeat="col in headerList2" ng-switch="col">

                                <span ng-switch-when="lstDetail"> <button type="button" ng-click="btnViewDetails_Click(index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">+</button></span>
                                <span ng-switch-default>{{ client[col] }}</span>

                             </td>

                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                              <td colspan="3">
                              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" dt-instance="dtInstance3" id="dtInvoicingData3"  dt-options="dtOptions3" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs3">
                                 <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th ng-repeat="col3 in headerList3">{{col3 | translate}} </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                 <tr ng-repeat="(index,client) in lstChildInvoiceDetail" class="clickableRow" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Click to toggle collapse/expand day summaries for this store.">
                                     <td ng-repeat="col3 in headerList3" ng-switch="col">

                                        <!-- <span ng-switch-when="lstDetail"> <button type="button" ng-click="btnViewDetails_Click(index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">+</button></span> -->
                                        <span ng-switch-default>{{ client[col3] }}</span>

                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                                </tbody>
                             </table>
                          </td> 
                           <td style="display:none;"> </td>
                          <td style="display:none;"></td>
                          </tr>     
                    </tbody>
                 </table>
```

Child Table is created on first row, i want to created on each row.

Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to create two rows with different structures instead of nested tables.

Row 1 :

```
<tr ng-repeat="(index,client) in lstInvoiceDetail" class="clickableRow" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Click to toggle collapse/expand day summaries for this store.">
        <td ng-repeat="col in headerList2" ng-switch="col">
            <span ng-switch-when="lstDetail"> <button type="button" ng-click="btnViewDetails_Click(index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">+</button></span>
            <span ng-switch-default>{{ client[col] }}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And Row 2 :

```
<tr ng-show="showViewDetail">
       <div class="span12 pull-right" ng-show="showViewDetail">
           <table datatable="ng"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" dt-instance="dtInstance3" id="dtInvoicingData3"  dt-options="dtOptions3" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs3">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th ng-repeat="col3 in dtColumnDefs3">{{col3.aTargets[0].sTitle | translate}} </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="(index,client) in lstInvoiceDetail" class="clickableRow" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Click to toggle collapse/expand day summaries for this store.">
                    <td ng-repeat="col3 in headerList3" ng-switch="col">
                        <span ng-switch-when="lstDetail"> <button type="button" ng-click="btnViewDetails_Click(index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">+</button></span>
                        <span ng-switch-default>{{ client[col3] }}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>                            
    </tr>
```

and as far error states, data in both rows has different count for header and columns. It means your lists `dtColumnDefs2`, `headerList2`, `dtColumnDefs3`,  and `headerList3` have different counts.