# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined when rowspan used

Tags: php, jquery, foreach, html-table, datatables

I have a table with records from database results populated using foreach loop.
The last column, "Roll Over", of the table, however, is a single cell value with rowspan attribute.
I'm using dataTable plugin for the table.

```
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="leave_balance_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Leave Type</th>
                <th>Max Days</th>
                <th>Leave Taken</th>
                <th>Leave Balance</th>
                <th>Roll Over</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $totalLeaveTaken = 0.00;
        $totalBalance = 0.00;
        $totalRows = count($GetEmployeeLeaveBalance);
        $lastColumnPrinted = false; //Add This
            foreach ($GetEmployeeLeaveBalance as $member):
                $totalLeaveTaken += $member['usedDays'];
                $totalBalance += $member['Remaining_Leave_Days'];
                $leaveBalance = floatval($member['Remaining_Leave_Days']);
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $member['title']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $member['maxDays']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $member['usedDays']; ?></td>
                <!-- <td><?php echo gettype($leaveBalance);?></td> -->
                <td
                <?= 
                ($leaveBalance < 0) ? 
                "style='background-color:red;font-weight:bold;color:white;'" : ""
                ?>
                >
                <?php echo $member['Remaining_Leave_Days']; ?>    
                </td>

                <!--Add The Line Below -->
                <?php if($lastColumnPrinted == false): $lastColumnPrinted = true;?>
                  <td rowspan="<?= $totalRows; ?>">Some computed value</td>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="background-color: #33CCFF; font-weight: bold;">Total: <?php echo number_format($totalLeaveTaken, 2); ?></td>
            <td style="background-color: #33CCFF; font-weight: bold;">Total: <?php echo 
            number_format($totalBalance, 2); ?></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The output is somewhat like this:

```
Leave Type | Max Days | Leave Taken | Leave Balance | Roll Over
Float      | 3        | 2           | 1             | 5
Personal   | 3        | 2           | 1             |   
Sick       | 3        | 2           | 1             | 
Mourning   | 3        | 2           | 1             |
```

The result is as expected, but I'm getting above mentioned error in the console.
Is it because there are empty cells in the table?

Comment: You must include that last `<td></td>` or  this will fail, if not wrong there a solution with JavaScript for empty solutions, just one sec

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataTables issue: VM9075 dataTables.min.js:24Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '\_DT\_CellIndex' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904708/datatables-issue-vm9075-datatables-min-js24uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-prop)

Comment: @William-H-M I added a <td></td> to last row. I don't want to match <th>s with <td>s. A last column cell will be common to all rows using rowspan. Can you help me with it

Comment: The thing is that DataTables [doesn't support](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/100662/#Comment_100662) [rowspan or colspan](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/110159/#Comment_110159) but [here this says](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/119433/#Comment_119433) that you can somewhow do it.